# How do I fix the mypy error Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

How do I fix the mypy error Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types?

Here are my methods:

```
    @typing.overload
    def _find_pets_by_tags(
        self,
        query_params: typing.Union[
            QueryParametersDictInput,
            QueryParametersDict
        ],
        security_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, float, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: typing_extensions.Literal[False] = False
    ) -> response_200.ApiResponse: ...

    @typing.overload
    def _find_pets_by_tags(
        self,
        query_params: typing.Union[
            QueryParametersDictInput,
            QueryParametersDict
        ],
        security_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, float, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: typing_extensions.Literal[True] = ...
    ) -> api_response.ApiResponseWithoutDeserialization: ...

    def _find_pets_by_tags(
        self,
        query_params: typing.Union[
            QueryParametersDictInput,
            QueryParametersDict
        ],
        security_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, float, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: bool = False
    ):
```

And mypy complains that:
`Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types  [misc]`

But

- how are these methods overlapping? They require two different literal bool inputs
- What makes the return types incompatible? The overload requires two different class instances are returned. Both of them inherit from an api_client.ApiResponse base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how are these methods overlapping? They require two different literal bool inputs

No they don't. `skip_deserialization` is *optional*, not required, in both overloads. A call that doesn't pass `skip_deserialization` can match both overloads.

> What makes the return types incompatible? The overload requires two different class instances are returned. Both of them inherit from an api_client.ApiResponse base class

It doesn't matter that both return types have a common supertype. (*All* Python types have a common supertype `object` anyway.) The fact remains that they are different types, and code written to expect one type may not be compatible with the other.

---

Since the actual default for `skip_deserialization` is `False`, it should not be optional in the overload that expects `True`. Since the parameter follows multiple arguments that *are* optional, you may need to change your overload structure, or change how this method takes that argument - for example, you might want to make it keyword-only (and while you're at it, it might make sense to make a bunch of the other arguments keyword-only too).

If you don't want to change how the method takes arguments, then one way to write the overloads would be to write two separate overloads, one where the argument is passed by keyword (and the other arguments remain optional), and one where the argument is passed positionally (requiring all previous arguments to be passed positionally, thus making them mandatory in that overload).

Comment: My overloads are hard coding in required values for skip_deserialization or trying to. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @spacether: The `= ...` in `skip_deserialization: typing_extensions.Literal[True] = ...` says that parameter is optional.